# In Lasagne/Theano, do I need a 4d numpy array for a 4d Theano tensor?

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, lasagne

I'm building a neural network with lasagne and am [following the example from the github.](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne) I'm curious on how exactly to input into the network. In the example they state that the input layer is 4 dimensions and indeed it is a theano tensor4. Does this mean I have to give the network a 4 dimensional numpy array? Is that even possible? How would you build one from a 4 d vector of lists?

Comment: yes, you need to give it a 4D input if you are treating e.g. color images. The axes are image index, color, vertical, horizontal. If you only have one RGB image, you should give it the shape `(1, 3, h, w)`

Comment: @ElliottMiller : did the provided answer help?

Answer (score 0):

In the MNIST example provided by Lasagne, you need to input a 4D tensor.

Generally speaking, if your data is 2 dimensional (images for example), the shape of your input must be `(n_samples, n_channels, height, width)`. In the MNIST dataset `n_channel` is 1 (might be something else, e.g. 3 for RGB images), and `height` and `width` are both 28.

If your data is only 1 dimensional, then you must input a 3D tensor, of shape `(n_samples, n_channel, n_features)`.

Note that this might be problematic if you want to predict a label for a single image ((28, 28) ndarray as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499761/get-output-from-lasagne-python-deep-neural-network-framework/32007540#32007540), because you need to make the input 4 dimensional. In this case, you can add axis using `data = data[None, None, :, :]`.